# Android AcousticEchoCanceler NOT Working

Tags: android, echo-cancellation

Hi I am trying to add VOIP feature to an android Application. For this I need Acoustic Echo Cancellation. 
I have seen the official documentation for AcousticEchoCanceler [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/media/audiofx/AcousticEchoCanceler.html). 
I am using this piece of code for Acoustic Echo Cancellation:

```
if(AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable()) {
            echoCanceler = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(mAudioRecord.getAudioSessionId());
            echoCanceler.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

But this does not seem to help at all. isAvailable() returns true and echoCanceler objects gets created. If I query echoCanceler.getEnabled() it returns true also.
 
Even if I make a sample app using AudioRecord and AudioTrack this does not work. I heard a lot of echo.
 
If I set the source of AudioRecord as:

> android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION

I see the echo gets cancelled in case of Nexus 5(for Android version 5 and 6).
(I am not using AcousticEchoCanceler when I set the source as VOICE_COMMUNICATION) However with same Android version, the same method does not work with Samsung Galaxy S4 and Samsung Note 4 etc devices.

Using echo Cancellation Libraries(like libspeexdsp etc) is NOT possible (as I am working on an existing project). 
Please help as soon as possible.
 Thank you very much.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem.

Devices that have AcousticEchoCanceler and seem to work:
    Nexus 5         (Android version : 6.0.1)
    Moto X             (Android version : 5.1.1)
Dont seem to work:
    Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime     (Android version : 5.1.1)
    Samsung Galaxy S6Edge        (Android version : 5.1.1)
    HTC One

Comment: Try setting the audio mode to `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`.

Comment: Vivek that was the issue in my case!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the audio mode is set to `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`